# VS2013 Git version control

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, git-branch, team-explorer

all.
There's a case study for learning Git branching, which is:

- Need to start a new feature;
- Meanwhile a bug comes is discovered and we need an urgent hotfix;

So the basic workflow would be create and checkout a "feature1" branch; do some commit along the work for that feature. When the bug is discovered we checkout "master" and create/checkout the "hotfix" branch. Commit work to fix the bug and merge "hotfix" into "master". And then checkout "feature1" branch.
I get this, it's safe, ease ti understand and makes a lot of sense.
But, for me, it would also make sense to have the hotfix changes in my "feature1" branch. How can I achieve this using Team Explorer in VS2013? (Note 1: I want a clean "master" branch so I don't think merging is an option.) (Note 2: In command line Git, would you advise a cherry-pick for the hotfix commit? Or rebase, but rebase doesn't mess up the hash?) Sorry, a lot of questions.
One more only: When you delete a branch in VS2013 all the branche's commits are keept, right?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

1) Keep master clean, don't merge or commit to it.
2) Create a "develop" branch.
3) Create any branches you want from develop
4) Always PR your branches to develop and that'll keep your work flow clean.
5) When you want to deploy, create a "deply-02272015" branch and tag it, and deploy that branch (which would be a copy of develop with latest goodness in it).
Not sure about VS2013, but cmd line or TortoiseGit are great tools to use when git'ing.

Comment: Thanks, Snolan. What I meant by a clean master branch is no pending features on it, just the nearest to production possible.